# jQuery go up button stopped working after worked once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, up-button

I have putted together some basic website features by applying jquery in a testing page and the features includes smooth scrolling, assign active class to focused section when scrolling up & down web page, shrinking navbar and go back to the top button. However, I realised that all these features stopped working once I added 'go back to the top btn' as it can only works once then everything stopped working and web site just 'dead' and can't even scroll down. I have done some reserach and corrected my code from using '.click()' alone to applying '.on(event, func)' as someone experienced the same thing as I did, but still doesn't help. 
Can someone take a look at my code and please let me know what else I should change it in order to make it work properly. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var scrollLink = $('.scroll');
  // smooth scrolling feature  
    scrollLink.on('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top
        }, 900)
    })

   

    $(window).scroll(function() {

        var scrollbarLocation = $(this).scrollTop();
        var btn = $('.upBtn');

   // shrink the navbar once scrollbar moves down more than 50px
        if($('.navbar').offset().top > 50) {
            $('.navbar').addClass('navbar-shrink');
        } else {
            $('.navbar').removeClass('navbar-shrink');
        }

    // show users which section they are looking at by applying active class to each nav link
        scrollLink.each(function() {
            var sectionOffset = $(this.hash).offset().top - 55;
            if(sectionOffset <= scrollbarLocation) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active')
            } 
        })
    
    // show the go up bottom in the right bottom cornor once scroll bar moves down more then 100px 
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            btn.addClass('show');
        } else {
            btn.removeClass('show')
        }
    // scrolling back up to the top once btn being clicked
    // I have changed my code to '.on' after done some reseatch but the button still not working once being clicked and working once.
        btn.on('click',function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 900)
        })
    })

})
```

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
}

#home {    
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#about {
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}

#contact {
    background-color: lightpink;
}

.active {
    background-color: blue !important;
}

.navbar {
    transition: all .4s ease-in 0s;
}

.navbar-shrink {
    padding-top: .2rem;
    padding-bottom: .2rem;
    transition: all .4s ease-in 0s;
    background: transparent !important;
}

.upBtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2rem;
    right: 2rem;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>jQuery Smooth Scrolling</title>
</head>

<body>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
                aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#home">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <section id='home'></section>
    <section id='about'></section>
    <section id='contact'></section>

    <a href="#" class="upBtn">Up</a>
   <!-- jQuery cdn has to be full version not slim as slim version dosen't include the animation features-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src='main.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: One thing I'll point out: Realize that the `scroll` event is called hundreds of times during scrolling. By having code that creates new events *inside* of that event, like `btn.on('click',function(e) { ... }`, you're attaching hundreds (if not thousands) of `click` events to your button. Clicking that button is going to fire **all** of those events simultaneously. Likewise, it's not a great idea to have selectors inside this event for elements that aren't dynamic, like your `up` button. You continue to look it up hundreds of times, when you really only need to look it up once.

Comment: The code is messy and I can see that and what is the correct way to organize it, have you got a link or reference that I can study. By the way, any reason why the all the btn stopped working once up button was clicked. I still could not figure it out and it seems that there some kind of conflicts within the code.thanks